# Looking for short story with main character in reverse time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

It is a perfunctory cats and mouse "fugitive" scenario in a small town BUT the "mouse" is living in "reverse time" and it is handled extremely competently. I'm sure it was an early early early P.K.D. (but not [*Counter-Clock World*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?950)) but maybe not. Certainly from the fifties...

Comment: Can you remember **anything** about the story except "reverse time" and "small town"? Is the main character a man or a woman? Is the story set in America? In the past, present, or future? Is there a murder in the story? How do you know it was from the fifties? When did you read it?

Comment: *Counter-Clock World* was based on a novelette called ["Your Appointment Will Be Yesterday"](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v40n07_1966-08/page/n5/mode/2up) but I guess that's not it either?

Comment: Boucher's ["The Chronokinesis of Jonathan Hull"](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v37n04_1946-06_cape1736#page/n117/mode/1up) is a good early reverse-time story, but it's **too** early (1946, not the fifties), and set in Los Angeles, not a small town, so that's not it.

Comment: "perfunctory cats and mouse 'fugitive' scenario" must be an important clue. What does it mean?

Comment: Thanks to all but I don't think we got it. @user14111 the whole thing was like "he dashed around the brick corner whence a bullet ricocheted, etc." I can't remember if the bullet was reversed. I think the protag was male, but maybe...an "allien." It might have been a city...Doesn't sound like P.K.D., but as I said it was competent...   j.

Answer (score 1):

The story of Benjamin Button comes to mind, but does not have the 'cat and mouse" elements you mention.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curious_Case_of_Benjamin_Button_(film)

(Mods may wish to move this to a comment)

Comment: How does that story match the question? Why "Benjamin Button" instead of one of the many other reversed-time stories?

Comment: By the way, why did you link to the Wikipedia page about the movie, instead of the F. Scott Fitzgerald short story? The OP didn't say anything about a movie.